# Winston not logging correct values

Tags: javascript, express, logging, winston

Hey everyone i need help setting up my Winston logging config.
I am migrating an existing project with 300 + console.logs to winston and now the values of the logs are not printed anymore.
I researched online and only found hacky solutions that didn't work for me.
Any help is appreciated.

```
This is my logger config
    // logger config
    const winston = require('winston')
    const { combine, timestamp, colorize, align, printf } = winston.format
    const logger = winston.createLogger({
      // level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info',
      level: 'silly',
      format: combine(
        colorize({ all: true }),
        timestamp({
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss',
        }),
        align(),
        printf((info) => `[${info.timestamp}] ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)
      ),  transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
    })
    module.exports = logger
```

This is how the console log was before:

```
console.log('active jobs : ',
              (await queue.getActive()).length)
```

Output:

> active jobs : 12

This is how it is now:

```
logger.info(
          'active jobs : ',
          (await queue.getActive()).length
        )
```

Output:

> [2022-05-23 03:57:29] info:     active jobs :

I would appreciate if there is a possibility without changing the console.logs since they are so many.